# Convert array of custom object to String in swift4

Tags: arrays, dictionary, nsdictionary, swift4, swift-string

I am new to Swift and have an issue converting an array of custom object, to String.

This is my response class **Tickets**

```
public struct Tickets: Codable {
        public let name: String!
        public let status: String!
        public let department: String!
    }
```

After the webservice call i get following response and it would be mapped to Tickets class. Now, I have an array of "Tickets" as [Tickets] described below.

```
"tickets": [
    {
      "name": "d5b5d618-8a74-4e5f",
      "status": "VALID",
      "department": "IT"
    },
    {
      "name": "a58f54b5-9420-49b6",
      "status": "INVALID",
      "department": "Travel"
    }
  ]
```

Now, can I convert an array of `[Tickets]` to String? If so, how? Also, how to get it back as `[Tickets]` from a class of `String`.

I want to store it into UserDefaults after converting it to String, and retrieve it later

Comment: you could [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map) (or [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2903427-flatmap)) a collection anytime at your convenience; that could work in any ways... isn't that good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

**Never declare properties or members in a struct or class as implicit unwrapped optional if they are supposed to be initialized in an `init` method. If they could be `nil` declare them as regular optional (`?`) otherwise as non-optional (Yes, the compiler won't complain if there is no question or exclamation mark).**

Just decode and encode the JSON with `JSONDecoder()` and `JSONEncoder()`

```
let jsonTickets = """
{"tickets":[{"name":"d5b5d618-8a74-4e5f","status":"VALID","department":"IT"},{"name":"a58f54b5-9420-49b6","status":"INVALID","department":"Travel"}]}
"""

public struct Ticket: Codable {
    public let name: String
    public let status: String
    public let department: String
}

do {
    let data = Data(jsonTickets.utf8)
    let tickets = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[Ticket]].self, from: data)
    print(tickets)
    let jsonTicketsEncodeBack = try JSONEncoder().encode(tickets)
    jsonTickets == String(data: jsonTicketsEncodeBack, encoding: .utf8) // true
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Yes, I take your words in bold and do the changes in the struct. Thanks